# Application names aren't unique, duplicates: accounts

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to run a python manage.py makemigration command, but i'm greeted with the following error message:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application labels aren't unique, duplicates: accounts
```

I attempted to add the following to my accounts.apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class AccountsConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'accounts'
    label = 'my_accounts'
```

But, that gives me the following error message:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Application names aren't unique, duplicates: accounts
```

My security.settings.py installed apps is the following:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'accounts',
    'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Is this error message because I have 'accounts', and accounts.apps.accountsconfig in my installed_apps?  How can I get AccountsConfig to be part of my installed apps to allow for my migration?  Below is my applications folder structure.

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93Kl9.png)

I am adding my migration with the following:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models


class AllEeActive(models.Model):
    employee_last_name = models.CharField(db_column='Employee_Last_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    employee_first_name = models.CharField(db_column='Employee_First_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    employee_ntname = models.CharField(db_column='Employee_NTName',primary_key=True, serialize=False, max_length=50)  # Field name made lowercase.
    b_level = models.CharField(db_column='B_Level', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    group_name = models.CharField(db_column='Group_Name', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    r_level = models.CharField(db_column='R_Level', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    division_name = models.CharField(db_column='Division_Name', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    d_level = models.CharField(db_column='D_Level', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    market_name = models.CharField(db_column='Market_Name', max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    coid = models.CharField(db_column='COID', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    unit_no = models.CharField(db_column='Unit_No', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    dept_no = models.CharField(db_column='Dept_No', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    department_desc = models.CharField(db_column='Department_Desc', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    employee_status = models.CharField(db_column='Employee_Status', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    job_desc = models.CharField(db_column='Job_Desc', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    position_desc = models.CharField(db_column='Position_Desc', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    supervisor_last_name = models.CharField(db_column='Supervisor_Last_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    supervisor_first_name = models.CharField(db_column='Supervisor_First_Name', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    supervisor_job_desc = models.CharField(db_column='Supervisor_Job_Desc', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    cfo = models.CharField(db_column='CFO', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    email_address = models.CharField(db_column='Email_Address', max_length=250, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    location_code = models.CharField(db_column='Location_Code', max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    location_code_desc = models.CharField(db_column='Location_Code_Desc', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    corporate_flag = models.CharField(db_column='Corporate_Flag', max_length=1, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    hire_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Hire_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    termination_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Termination_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    employee_status_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Employee_Status_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    qv_statusid = models.IntegerField(db_column='QV_StatusID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    lawson_status_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Lawson_Status_ID', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    load_date = models.DateTimeField(db_column='Load_Date', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'All_EE_Active'
```

Then I'm trying to run the following with my python shell to verify the migration went through:

```
>>> from accounts.models import AllEeActive
>>> All_EE_Active.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'All_EE_Active' is not defined
>>> AllEEActive.objects.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'AllEEActive' is not defined
```

Why does python not recognize All_EE_Active or AllEeActive?  It appears to accept the import.

Comment: Remove `'accounts.apps.AccountsConfig',` . It's basically the same thing
as accounts. And then move `accounts` to the bottom so the django inbuilt apps will be loaded first.

Comment: If I do this then when i run makemigration and migrate, my models aren't loaded.

Comment: have you moved accounts below staticfiles? Move it to the bottom of the list and report what error you get.

Comment: I did move accounts below staticfiles, I receive no error message, but my database isn't migrated correctly.  I see everything in models, and my 0001_initial.py migrations.

Comment: if you have no important data, it's best you delete the migration folder and redo the migrations.

Comment: I can't delete the database tables, but i deleted all my django migration files.    Every table i'm creating a migration to has 'managed':False as I just want to read the existing EDW.

Comment: I also updated the problem up top to show the migration in accounts.models.py and to show what's happening when running AllEeActive.objects.all()

Comment: Tried reproducing the issue and had no problems? You might have to manually check your db to ensure that the migration actually went through. Did you mean the `python manage.py shell` or just `python` on the terminal?

Comment: python manage.py shell, i seen the migration in the db, i dropped it and loaded a new one, but i'm unable to view it after importing in the shell.